# Django include template tag multiple template choices

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I have a requirement where in I have to include a template inside a template tag. But the template I want to include is not fixed. I have list of templates and whichever is found first need to be included.

The include template tag however takes only a single template name.
Is there a way to modify this behavior or any other way to achieve this.

I was using custom template tag for the same, but I am getting warning since updating to django 1.9 that

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: render() must be called with a dict, not a RequestContext.
return t.render(context)
```

This is my custom template tag

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def custom_include(context, *template_choices):
    template_choices = (context['optionalTemplate'],) + template_choices
    t = template.loader.select_template(template_choices)
    return t.render(context)
```

I tried getting dict from context, and it seemed to work (atleast I thought that). But some of the context data went missing. For example my google analytics hits went to zero and that sort of stuff.

```
request = context['request']
mydict = context.dicts[0]
return t.render(mydict, request)
```

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try to make a dict out of the context? `return t.render(dict(context))`. I'm not sure if it works. If RequestContext is an object, you can inspect if it contains the dict with vars you are interested in. Something like `context.some_dict_name`.

Comment: I tried that too, and it seemed to work (atleast I thought that). But some of the context data went missing. For example my google analytics hits went to zero and that sort of stuff. See my update to the question

Comment: Maybe `t.render_to_string(context_instance=request_context)`? In the Django 1.10 release notes there is also a mention: 'Django template objects returned by get_template() and select_template() no longer accept a Context in their render() method.' https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/ I didn't look further for a related ticket. But the reason for this should live in the tracker. https://code.djangoproject.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flatten the context into a single dict. This will merge the data from all the internal dicts:

```
mydict = context.flatten()
return t.render(mydict, context.request)
```

Also check [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.Context.flatten).

Comment: hey thanks, it's working. I just need to monitor google analytics for few hours to verify that as well